# Merging backup and live data (Novice Question)

Tags: mysql, sql

It's been 30 years since I did any SQL, and never beyond beginner stage. Trying to recover from disaster. We have a main database that is visible from our website. And a backup copy taken a month ago.  Table (for one example) is wp_posts. There are some records unique to each database's version of the table and some records that are in both.

I need to UNION the two versions to get a version of the table with all the records, but no duplicates that I will make the live version. I found the description of the UNION operator, but it requires the two tables to be in the same database, so one solution might be to copy (and rename) one table from one DB to the other, do the UNION, then load the results into the live version of the table.

Any better ideas? What is the syntax for the four (I suspect) operations:
1. Unload the data from table
2. Load data into a new table in the other database
3. Union the tabes
4. Load results into live table.
Thanks from a beginner,
Phil

Comment: If both databases are on the same host server and accessible to the same database user, then you can join tables across databases.

Comment: Can you please add a tag with the database you are using?  The solutions vary according to provider.